# How to redirect page after clicking submit via Jquery Form Validator

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, redirect, submit

I'm using [Jquery Form Validator](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/) to validate my registration form for my site and while it does validate successfully, it refreshes the page when I click submit and not redirect directly to another page. Here's what I have:

```
<script>    
    $(document).ready(function() {


        $("#formID").validationEngine({
            submitHandler: function(form){
            window.location="report.html"
            }

    });

        function validate2fields(){
        if($("#addressl1").val() =="" ||  $("#addressl2").val() == ""){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    } 
    });

    </script>
```

I'm using a simple "submit" button and I've tried adding the link into the button but that didn't work at all. Here it is:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
```

I'm a beginner at this so I apologize if I've used the wrong terminology. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whats the `<form action="..." ...>`? (Is it defaulting to standard behavior?)

Comment: I didn't add a form action so it looks like `<form action="">` right now. There isn't any for the submit button either.

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.location.replace("url")` instead of `window.location="report.html".`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use window.location.replace("report.html") or window.location="report.html", first change the button type to 'button' i.e.,

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit">
```

For submit buttons, 'window.location' will not work.

Otherwise use this method

```
$("#form").attr("action","report.html");
$("#form").attr("method", "post");
$("#form").submit();
```

In this method also button type should be 'button', not 'submit'.